# Is there an abbreviation for "we want to prove that"?

Tags: proof-writing, notation

I think it's possible to abbreviate "such that" into "s.t." but is there an abbreviation for "we want to prove that"? Because this statement keeps repeating in proving inequalities.

Comment: I've seen "w.t.s." for "want to show"

Comment: I do not recommend using such abbreviations, they are ugly and worsen the readability. Use synonyms instead: "we claim that", "we need that" etc...

Comment: Prove or prove not, there is no want. -- Yoda

Comment: Sometimes (in lectures, not in handouts) I've seen "**Want**: (suff)". This is used in order to keep track of what sub-lemma a discussion that may need a certain number of blackboards is dealing with. But it's more of an ad hoc thing. In an actual paper you may be a pal to readers and be as discursive as you can, without being verbose. Keep in mind that the number of people that may want to read it widely outrange your possibility to explain your notation.

Comment: I had a real analysis lecturer use $\vdash :$, as in "$\vdash :$ $f_n\to f$" meaning "we want to prove that $f_n\to f$". I adopted that in the blackboard only, always saying the "we want to prove that" part a bit slower, exactly as I wrote the $\vdash :$.

Comment: References http://www.libragold.com/blog/2011/12/mathematical-abbreviation/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations

Answer (score 1):

In my undergraduate math classes, I have seen some faculty use "WTS:" as shorthand for "Want to show:". I found this to be quite convenient, but only after the meaning was explained: until then it was quite confusing, so do take @GiuseppeNegro's comment above into account.

If you feel you are going to be making repeated use of it in a document/exam paper then you could mention at the start what this abbreviation stands for exactly.